# mail attachment filename coding

Tags: email, unicode, smtpmail, attachment

I try to use mu4e with smtpmail to send mail, and use `mml-attach-file` to add attachment.

If the attachment filename contains non-english name, such as Chinese, the header of message will become `Content-Disposition: attachment;
 =?us-ascii?Q?filename=3D=22=3D=3Futf-8=3FB=3F5aSN5Lmg5o+Q57qyLTE5LmRvY3g?=`, which can show correct filename in mu4e. And there is a `utf-8` coding in this header.

But, it cannot be shown in some web mail client such as zoho and gmail and some local client. They display the name by themselves rules such as the mail's subject. And I check the one's header which attachment filename can be shown correctly, it is `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*0*=utf-8''...` or `filename="=?UTF-8...`

The first term of my emacs's coding-system in priority list is `utf-8`. `sendmail-coding-system` and `mm-coding-system` are `nil` or `utf-8`, which `nil` means use the same as emacs configuration.

My language environment is `English`, and I also tried to set it to `UTF-8`, but it is no effect.

By the way, my shell variable of `LANG` is `en_US.UTF-8`.

Is there a way to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `rfc2047-encode-encoded-words` to nil can make it work.

Comment: What do you mean "close" ?